# Getting wrong value with #define function

Tags: c++

There is one function defined in two different ways, one using #define and other using a function. But for the output I am getting different values.

The output is coming out to be `3 -1`.

I want to know why using `F(x,y)` results in different values.

```
#include<iostream>
#define F(x,y) y-x
using namespace std;

int F2(int x,int y)
{
    return y-x;
}

int main()
{
    int x=1,y=2, h=2;
    cout << F(x+h,y) << " " << F2(x+h,y) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Probably (some missing parens), a common gotcha with macros. *Avoid them* for silly stuff like this.

Comment: And the lesson here is.... ?

Comment: Rather than using a #define for a function, best to use an inline function, `inline int F(int x, int y) {return y-x;}`  You get MUCH better compiler diagnostics (say, passing in two pointers, which can compile OK in the original #define macro, but you may not actually want)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Classic problem using `#define`, and one of the main reasons why macros are discouraged. Keep in mind that a macro is little more than a literal substitution, and consider what it expands to:

```
cout << y-x+h << " " << F2(x+h,y) << endl;
```

And `y-x+h` is something very different from `y-(x+h)`.

Always parenthesize uses of macro arguments:

```
#define F(x,y) ((y)-(x))
```

Comment: It really should be what @[EugeneSh.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26981377/2721883) mentions so you can do (e.g) `F(x+h,y) * 3` properly.

Comment: @clcto You're absolutely right, thanks! See, that's why I avoid macros ;)

Answer (score 3):

First off, you didn't `#define` a *function* but a *macro*. Macros do straight text replacement so the output line is equivalent to:

```
cout << y-x+h << " " << F2(x+h,y) << endl;
```

Can you spot the error now?

Comment: To add to the answer - this is exactly the reason why you _ALWAYS_ put macro arguments (if you actually do sth with it) in parentheses.

Answer (score 1):

`#define` is a macro directive, not a function. It is just replacing it's occurrences by the macro body. If you do so, you will see that `F(x+h,y)` is replaced by `y-x+h`, which is obviously not what you want. The rule for macros is to take all of the parameters and subexpressions into brackes like this:

```
#define F(x,y) ((y)-(x))
```

in order to get the correct results. 
This way `F(x+h,y)` will be replaced by ((y)-(x+h)), which is correct